# Correct sequence of MSSQL Server updates

Tags: sql-server, update

What is the correct sequence to follow when updating MSSQL Server to a new service pack?

For example, if I have an instance of MSSQL Server 2016 RTM and I wish to update to SP2, do I need to first update to SP1 and and any of the cumulative updates in between or is it only necessary to update to SP2?

If there were cumulative updates available for SP2, would I need to first update to SP2 before running the latest cumulative update or is it only necessary to run the latest cumulative update?